# Set a global minimum amount in WooCommerce cart except for the category catering + subcategories

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, checkout, minimum

i'm trying to Set a minimum order amount in general of 51.50 € EXCEPT for the category "Catering + subcategaries" that can be added individually regardless of the amount in cart.

So far i found two codes, which works separatly fine. Now im trying to merge this two functions into one function because of the error messages.
Currently there is always the global error message because of the first function, even if catering products are found in the cart, through the second function.

```
/**
 * Set a minimum order amount for checkout - works fine
*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value - 51.50
    $minimum = 51.50;

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf( '| Ihr Bestellwert muss mindestens %s (inkl.Versandkosten) betragen um eine Bestellung abzugeben. —  Ihr aktueller Warenwert liegt bei %s.' ,
                    wc_price( $minimum ),
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error'
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice(
                sprintf( 'Ihr Bestellwert muss mindestens %s (inkl.Versandkosten) betragen um eine Bestellung abzugeben. —  Ihr aktueller Warenwert liegt bei %s.' ,
                    wc_price( $minimum ),
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error'
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Code to check, is there a catering product in the cart, which works fine but separately at the moment:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'minimum_order_amount_for_subcategories' );
function minimum_order_amount_for_subcategories() {
    $term_slug   = 'catering'; // <==  Define the targeted main product category slug
    $threshold   = 51.50; // <==  Define the minimum amount threshold

    $taxonomy    = 'product_cat'; // WooCommerce product category taxonomy
    $subtotal    = 0; // Itintializing
    $found       = false; // Itintializing
    
    // Get the children terms Ids from the main product category term slug
    $main_term   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
    $childen_ids = get_term_children( $main_term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $terms_ids   = array_merge( array($main_term->term_id), $childen_ids);
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for specific product category children term ids
        if ( has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; // At least subcategory is found
            
            // Get non discounted subtotal including taxes from subcategories
            $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax']; 
            
            
        }
    }

    if ( $found && $subtotal < $threshold ) {
        
        wc_add_notice( sprintf(
            __( "Bestellwert muss mindestens %s der Kategorie %s betragen", "woocommerce" ),
            wc_price($threshold),
            '"<strong>' . ucfirst($term_slug) . '</strong>"' 
        ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Thanks Kind regards,
Mazze

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain :) But once you see the finished code, next time you'll be able to handle any "conditional logic" functionality.

This should work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {

    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value - 51.50
    $threshold = 51.50;
    $term_slug = 'catering';
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // WooCommerce product category taxonomy
    $subtotal = 0; // Initializing
    $found = false; // Initializing

    // Get the children terms Ids from the main product category term slug
    $main_term   = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $main_term->term_id, $taxonomy );
    $terms_ids = array_merge( array($main_term->term_id), $children_ids);

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for specific product category children term ids
        if ( has_term( $terms_ids, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $found = true; // At least subcategory is found
    
            // Get non discounted subtotal including taxes from subcategories
            $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax']; 

        }
    }

    if ( $found && $subtotal < $threshold ) {

        if ( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice(
                sprintf( '| Ihr Bestellwert muss mindestens %s (inkl.Versandkosten) betragen um eine Bestellung abzugeben. —  Ihr aktueller Warenwert liegt bei %s.' ,
                    wc_price( $minimum ),
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error'
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice(
                sprintf( 'Ihr Bestellwert muss mindestens %s (inkl.Versandkosten) betragen um eine Bestellung abzugeben. —  Ihr aktueller Warenwert liegt bei %s.' ,
                    wc_price( $minimum ),
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total )
                ), 'error'
            );

        }
    }
}
```